# Performance tuning and optimization of XML::Twig in Perl

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

Following is the code I have scribbled in order to filter my 3 to 5 GB XML file based on four conditions:

Following are the conditions:

1) All sub-stocks should be filtered.

2) Stocks having certain origin should persist. Else all should be filtered.

3) Inside the stock trade, there is an `<event>` tag which subsequently has a `<subevent>` tag. For the `<event>` tag attribute 'code' should have value 'abc' and the `<subevent>` tag should have certain values for their attributes as can be seen in code.

4) Only the highest version (attribute of stock) for a given ref (another attribute of stock) should be persisted with. The rest should all be deleted (This one is the most complicated condition)

My code is:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

open( my $out, '>:utf8', 'out.xml') or die "cannot create output file  out.xml: $!";
my $twig = new XML::Twig(
    twig_roots => {  '/STOCKEXT/STOCK/STOCK'=> sub { $_->delete() },
                     '/STOCKEXT/STOCK[@origin != "ASIA"]' => sub  { $_->delete; },
                     '/STOCKEXT/STOCK' => \&trade_handler
                  },
    att_accessors => [ qw/ ref version / ],
    pretty_print  => 'indented',
);

my %max_version;
$twig->parsefile('1513.xml');
for my $stock ($twig->root->children('STOCK'))
{
   my ($ref, $version) = ($trade->ref, $trade->version);

   if ($version  eq  $max_version{$ref} &&
   grep {grep {$_->att('code') eq 'abc' and $_->att('narrative') eq 'def'}
   $_->children('subevent')} $trade->children('event[@eventtype="ghi"]'))

   {
        $trade->flush($out);
   }

   else
   {
    $trade->purge;

   }
}

sub trade_handler
{
  my ($twig, $trade) = @_;
  {
    my ($ref, $version) = ($trade->ref, $trade->version);

    unless (exists $max_version{$ref} and $max_version{$ref} >= $version)
    {
      $max_version{$ref} = $version;
    }
}

 1;
}
```

Sample XML

```
<STOCKEXT>
  <STOCK origin = "ASIA" ref="12" version="1" >(Filtered out, lower version ref)
    <event eventtype="ghi">
      <subevent code = "abc" narattive = "def" /> 
    </event>
  </STOCK>
  <STOCK origin = "ASIA" ref="12" version="2" >(highest version=2  for ref=12)
    <event eventtype="ghi">
      <subevent code = "abc" narattive = "def" /> 
    </event>
  </STOCK>
  <STOCK origin = "ASI" ref="13" version="1" >(Fileterd out "ASI" val wrong)   
    <event eventtype="ghi">
      <subevent code = "abc" narattive = "def" /> 
    </event>
  </STOCK>
```

Code is working absolutely fine and providing requisite output. But it's consuming a hell of a lot of memory, even though I have tried to implement "FLUSH" & "PURGE". Can anybody please help with some optimization tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're worried about the memory footprint, you really want to be using flush/purge in a twig handler.
That way it's called as the file is being parsed.

Your calls to purge are being made *after* your parsefile, which means - it has to load and parse the whole thing first.

You might be able to build part of that into your `trade_handler` - e.g. you test for a max version, and then compare it in your iteration loop later. So you could *probably* test that condition during the handler:

```
if ( $max_version{$ref} > $version ) { $trade -> purge; }
```

But bear in mind if you did this, you'd need to rethink your post-parse `foreach` loop, because you'd be discarding as you went.

I'm not entirely sure what your `grep` is for though. You could possibly also implement that logic in your trade_handler too, but I can't say for sure. (e.g. negative test, purge if this element isn't required).

I think - pretty fundamentally - you should be able to use a handler for your 'for' loop, and process and purge as you go. I can't tell for sure - you might need a two-pass approach, because of needing to look ahead for version numbers.

Edit: This doesn't quite do what you want, but hopefully illustrates what I'd be suggesting:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

open( my $out, '>:utf8', 'out.xml' )
    or die "cannot create output file  out.xml: $!";
my $twig = new XML::Twig(
    twig_roots => {
        '/STOCKEXT/STOCK/STOCK'              => sub { $_->delete() },
        '/STOCKEXT/STOCK[@origin != "ASIA"]' => sub { $_->delete; },
        '/STOCKEXT/STOCK' => \&trade_handler
    },
    att_accessors => [qw/ ref version /],
    pretty_print  => 'indented',
);

my %max_version;
my %best_version_of;

local $/;
$twig->parse(<DATA>);

foreach my $ref ( keys %best_version_of ) {
  $best_version_of{$ref} -> print;
}
#$twig->parsefile('1513.xml');


sub trade_handler {
    my ( $twig, $trade ) = @_;
    my ( $ref, $version ) = ( $trade->ref, $trade->version );

    if ( not exists $max_version{$ref}
        or $max_version{$ref} < $version )
    {
        ###something here that replicates your grep test, as I'm not sure I've got it right. 
        $max_version{$ref}     = $version;
        $best_version_of{$ref} = $trade;
    }   
  $trade -> purge;
}


__DATA__

<STOCKEXT>
  <STOCK origin = "ASIA" ref="12" version="1" >
    <event eventtype="ghi">
      <subevent code = "abc" narattive = "def" /> 
    </event>
  </STOCK>
  <STOCK origin = "ASIA" ref="12" version="2" >
    <event eventtype="ghi">
      <subevent code = "abc" narattive = "def" /> 
    </event>
  </STOCK>
  <STOCK origin = "ASI" ref="13" version="1" >
    <event eventtype="ghi">
      <subevent code = "abc" narattive = "def" /> 
    </event>
  </STOCK> 
</STOCKEXT>
```

As said, this doesn't quite do what you want - it'll 'save memory' only as long as you're able to discard a lot of the XML by purging it as you go along... but because you don't know which version is the highest until you get to the end, a memory footprint is inevitable, because you'll never entirely know what you can safely discard until you get there.

So perhaps you need a two-pass approach, where you parse first to extract 'highest version numbers' - much like you're doing, but purging as you go... and then start over once you know them, because then you know what you can purge or flush as you're going.

The reason you're having this problem is that you can't know if you've got the latest version until you hit the end of the file.

So you might need to do something like this instead?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

open( my $out, '>:utf8', 'out.xml' )
    or die "cannot create output file  out.xml: $!";

my $first_pass = new XML::Twig(
    twig_roots => {
        '/STOCKEXT/STOCK/STOCK'              => sub { $_->delete() },
        '/STOCKEXT/STOCK[@origin != "ASIA"]' => sub { $_->delete; },
        '/STOCKEXT/STOCK' => \&extract_highest_version,
    },
    att_accessors => [qw/ ref version /],
    pretty_print  => 'indented',
);

my $main_parse = new XML::Twig(
    twig_roots => {
        '/STOCKEXT/STOCK/STOCK'              => sub { $_->delete() },
        '/STOCKEXT/STOCK[@origin != "ASIA"]' => sub { $_->delete; },
        '/STOCKEXT/STOCK' => \&trade_handler
    },
    att_accessors => [qw/ ref version /],
    pretty_print  => 'indented',
);

my %max_version_of;

$first_pass->parsefile('1513.xml');
$main_parse->parsefile('1513.xml');

sub extract_highest_version {
    my ( $twig, $trade ) = @_;
    my ( $ref, $version ) = ( $trade->ref, $trade->version );

    if ( not exists $max_version_of{$ref}
        or $max_version_of{$ref} < $version )
    {
        $max_version_of{$ref} = $version;
    }
    $trade->purge;
}

sub trade_handler {
    my ( $twig, $trade ) = @_;
    my ( $ref, $version ) = ( $trade->ref, $trade->version );
    if ( $version >= $max_version_of{$ref}
        and ( $trade->first_child('event')->att('eventtype')                           eq 'ghi' )
        and ( $trade->first_child('event')->first_child('subevent')->att('code')       eq 'abc' )
        and ( $trade->first_child('event')->first_child('subevent') ->att('narattive') eq 'def' )
        )
    {
        $trade->flush;
    }
    else {
        $trade->purge;
    }
}
```

Can probably be a bit tidier, but the point is - you run through it once - and `purge` as you go, so you only have a single `<STOCK>` in memory at a given time. Then you have a relationship between 'ref' and 'highest version.

So then you parse a second time, and because you know what the highest version is, you can purge/flush as you go - you don't have to read the future.

Now as noted in the comments - your first approach reads the whole file into memory, because it needs to know the 'highest version'. It's single pass though, which makes it faster.

The other approach is two pass - reading the file twice. Slower, but not retaining very much in memory at all.

A halfway house might be:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

open( my $out, '>:utf8', 'out.xml' )
    or die "cannot create output file  out.xml: $!";
my $twig = new XML::Twig(
    twig_roots => {
        '/STOCKEXT/STOCK/STOCK'              => sub { $_->delete() },
        '/STOCKEXT/STOCK[@origin != "ASIA"]' => sub { $_->delete; },
        '/STOCKEXT/STOCK' => \&trade_handler
    },
    att_accessors => [qw/ ref version /],
    pretty_print  => 'indented',
);

my %max_version_of;
my %best_version_of;

$twig->parsefile('1513.xml');

print {$out} "<STOCKEXT>\n";
foreach my $ref ( keys %best_version_of ) {
    foreach my $trade ( @{ $best_version_of{$ref} } ) {
        $trade->print($out);
    }
}
print {$out} "</STOCKEXT>\n";

sub trade_handler {
    my ( $twig, $trade ) = @_;
    my ( $ref, $version ) = ( $trade->ref, $trade->version );

    if ((   not defined $max_version_of{$ref}
            or $version >= $max_version_of{$ref}
        )
        and ( $trade->first_child('event')->att('eventtype') eq 'ghi' )
        and
        ( $trade->first_child('event')->first_child('subevent')->att('code')
            eq 'abc' )
        and ( $trade->first_child('event')->first_child('subevent')
            ->att('narattive') eq 'def' )
        )
    {
        if ( not defined $max_version_of{$ref}
            or $version >= $max_version_of{$ref} )
        {
           #this version is higher, so anything lower is redundant - remove it
            @{ $best_version_of{$ref} } = ();
        }
        push( @{ $best_version_of{$ref} }, $trade );
        $max_version_of{$ref} = $version;
    }
    $trade->purge;
    #can omit this, it'll just print how 'big' the hash is getting. 
    print "Hash size: ". %best_version_of."\n";
}
```

What this does is still purge as it goes, but slowly fills up `%best_version_of`. It might still have a big memory footprint though - it depends rather a lot on the ratio of 'keep' vs. 'discard'.

I'm afraid there's just no optimal solution - to figure out which version is 'newest' you have to run through the file twice, and either you do that at expense of memory consumption, or you do so at the expense of disk IO.

(And I think I have to offer a caveat - this won't produce 'valid' XML, because the root node `<STOCKEXT>` will be discarded. Putting that at the start of `$out` and `</STOCKEXT>` at the end will solve that though).

Comment: Can you please scribble the code...I mean re-write section of my code...in a way to implement your idea..I am slightly baffled..

Comment: Not easily. It's a significant change to how your thing works - you're iterating the XML post parse. To purge, you need to parse and purge as you go.

Comment: no...not always...sequence is not sure...But only those stocks need to be kept which have highest value for 'version' attribute  for the same ref values...In case if two <STOCK> have same highest value of version attribute for given ref....then both need to be kept..as they both are legitimate trades....

Comment: OK, I've updated with an example of how it _could_ go. You're still, unfortunately, retaining quite a bit in memory. So perhaps parsing it twice actually is necessary - first pass to determine highest version numbers, second pass to parse and discard. Not very efficient, but may be unavoidable, given you want to keep memory footprint down.

Comment: @sobrique-your idea sounds great....but since I have started perl recently...can you please scribble the code for me...

Comment: OK, edited again. Not sure that's the most efficient approach, but it might do the trick?

Comment: @sobrique....Thanx a ton ...bro...I am gonna work on it....But I guess...I understood the idea....

Comment: Hi bro...the performance has got degraded....Earlier for 500 mb file it was taking 13 minutes whereas now it's 24 mins (almost double)...Good thing is memory consumption is amazingly low....can this trade-off be averted??

Comment: It would be double, because it's doing it twice. This is a classic memory vs. processor tradeoff. With the problem as you've outlined it - I don't think there's a solution. You might be able to do something similar to my first example - that parses once, and partially discards as it goes. (e.g. retains `%best_version_of`). You'll need to modify it slightly to handle duplicates though, because as it stands two trades with the same ref and version will clobber each other.

Comment: some scribbling of code on your part will help..But can't ask for more...Bro..You have really helped a lot....Thanx...Best wishes

Comment: OK, given it a go. Not sure how much it'll help though - very much depends how many lines you discard vs. retain.

Comment: I'd also strongly recommend that you validate the results of these scripts. 'some guy on the internet' isn't a strong assertion of code quality :)